# Проблема с Laravel UI Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

установил вью так, как описано  в доках лары
сбилдил начальный апп:

```
    require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

mix отчитался, что все собрал успешно
на странице разместил

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

билд подключен

но экзампл компонент не нарисовался
в консоли браузера обьекта Vue тоже нет

```
"vue": "^2.6.12",
"vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
```

и Laravel Mix v6.0.43
кто знает или полагает ,что знает, как это исправить(заставить отрисоватся компонент) - пишите
введите сюда код
введите сюда код

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы подключили скомпилированный бандл в шаблон? Mix сам по себе никуда не подключает ничего, только билдит.